# Snap.svg - Getting boundary box of groups relative to the paper space

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, snap.svg

I am having a real hard time here. I am new to working with SVG and the Snap library.  What I am trying to do seems simple, but I have wasted an embarrassingly large amount of time on this...

I have a menu on the left side of the page that lists all elements in an SVG file that gets loaded using Snap.  Once the list is built, I assign a click() event to the menu items that is simply trying to create a new rectangle around the object or group (using getBBox or simliar) for the Snap object passed to it.  The new rectangle flashes bright yellow, then gets deleted.  This is intended to help the user identify which object in the list corresponds to which object in the image.

It seems to work as expected in the X direction, but is very confusing in the Y direction...especially when an object within a group is clicked.  Photos are attached:
Photo 1 shows the "before", with a very VERY simple SVG file loaded on the right.  Photo 2 shows after a click event, with the blinking fading from yellow back to the object's original color.

The menu on the left is built using FancyTree, and I am using jQuery in this project.

Below is the code in question.  If you scroll down you'll see THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS with several lines commented out of things I've tried.

```
    // make the selected element blink between red and yellow
selectBlink = function (element, thePaper){
    var oldColor = element.attr("fill");

    // create a Snap element from the inserted svg
    var existingSnap = new Snap("#snapTarget svg");

    // get the elements inside the loaded SVG
    var newGroup = existingSnap.selectAll();

    var boundary = element.getBBox();
    console.log("Boundary = ", boundary);
    console.log("x = ", boundary.x, " and y = ", boundary.y);
    console.log("cx = ", boundary.cx, " and cy = ", boundary.cy);
    console.log("h = ", boundary.h, " and w = ", boundary.w);

    var paperBoundary = thePaper.getBBox();

    var snapPaper   = document.getElementById("snapTarget");
    var snapBox = snapPaper.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log("snapBox = ", snapBox);
    console.log("Snap left = ", snapBox.left, " and top = ", snapBox.top );
    console.log("Snap height = ", snapBox.height, " and width = ", snapBox.width );

    var outerBoundary = element.node.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log("Outer Boundary = ", outerBoundary);
    console.log("left = ", outerBoundary.left, " and right = ", outerBoundary.right);
    console.log("top = ", outerBoundary.top, " and bottom = ", outerBoundary.bottom);
    console.log("height = ", outerBoundary.height, " and width = ", outerBoundary.width);


    console.log("Element = ", element);


    // create a new rectangle to surround the clicked object
    var x = boundary.x;
    // THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS, AND NONE OF THESE WORK AS EXPECTED:
    //var y = boundary.y;       
    //var y = snapBox.height-outerBoundary.height-boundary.height;
    //var y = 600-boundary.y-(boundary.h/2);
    var y = snapBox.height-boundary.y;
    //var y = snapBox.height-boundary.y-snapBox.top/2;
    var w = boundary.w;
    var h = boundary.h;


    var newRect = existingSnap.rect(x, y, w, h).attr({
        fill: colorRed
    });
    console.log("newRect = ", newRect);
    newRect.animate({fill: colorYellow}, 3000);         

    // Delete the select box after a few seconds
    setTimeout( function() {
      newRect.remove();
    }, 6000);

};
```

...and here are the photos, before and after the click event:
[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlN6t.png)

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjkJI.png)

Notice that the Y direction is not correct...this gets even weirder in groups.

Thanks, I'd really appreciate any pointers!

Comment: Can you put a working example with the other bits on a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Unless I am missing something, I dont know how to include the Snap.SVG library on a JSfiddle, as they have a ZIP file for their download link?

Comment: Just include the cdn in the external sources on the left, or include it as a script/src in your html... http://cdnjs.com/libraries/snap.svg/ copy paste https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg.js for example